# Blank screen after boot when image from buildroot is used

Tags: pi-zero, buildroot

I compiled the image using Buildroot (`2020.02.3`) by first running `make raspberrypi0_defconfig` and then by running `make menuconfig` to enable ccache and remove ifupdown scripts.

I then ran `make` to compile it to get a `sdcard.img` file which I wrote the files to sd card using `dd`.

When I boot the `Raspberry Pi Zero`, I see kernel messages and the last message I see is of init process starting and then the screen goes blank. Trying to switch to different TTY(s) by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + F1` (F1 to F7) don't work. I don't have any windows manager, so I expected a simple login prompt.

When I used the `Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) Lite - Minimal image based on Debian Buster`, I was able to boot just fine and get to the login prompt. I can login and it all works, except when I use the image built from buildroot.

What could it be?

Comment: Which shell did you include in the image? It looks like you forgot to include one.

Comment: I was relying on the defconfig to go with sane defaults. It had the value for `BR2_SYSTEM_BIN_SH` as `busybox' default shell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched the default shell to `/bin/sh`, essentially the variable `BR2_SYSTEM_BIN_SH="bash"` from busybox' default shell and I got the login prompt upon boot.

With `make menuconfig`, it was available under `System Configuration` > `/bin/sh`

I made some other changes as well, but I am quite sure this is what fixed it. I will accept my answer when I am sure of that.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.